# OnClick Expand the Kendo Treeview with all the child nodes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I already have Tree View as shown in the attachment, Now I have to Expand onclick of button, I know the code to perform Expand, but it doesn't expand complete child nodes, instead it does just only 1 immediate child, if it has more child, Please help me how to achive on single click to Expand all the Parent and Child nodes.
This is My code:

```
        $("#expand").on("click", function(){
                var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
                    treeview.expand(".k-item");
        })
```

Comment: Although slightly different, this should be what you are looking for: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/nodes/expand-all-nodes-upon-check

Answer (score 0):

If you call the expand method on treeview, it collapses all items:

```js
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: {
      data: [{
          text: "Item 1",
          expanded: true,
          items: [
            { 
               text: "Item 1.1", items: [ { text: "Item 1.4" }, { text: "Item 1.5" } ] 
            },
            { 
               text: "Item 1.2", items: [ { text: "Item 1.6" }, { text: "Item 1.7" } ] 
            },
            { 
               text: "Item 1.3", items: [{ text: "Item 1.8", items: [{ text: "Item 1.10" }, { text: "Item 1.11" } ] }, { text: "Item 1.9" } ] }
          ]
        },
        {
          text: "Item 2",
          items: [{ text: "Item 2.1" },
            { text: "Item 2.2" },
            { text: "Item 2.3" }
          ]
        },
        { text: "Item 3" }
      ]
    },
    loadOnDemand: false
  }).data("kendoTreeView"),

  handleTextBox = function(callback) {
    return function(e) {
      if (e.type != "keypress" || kendo.keys.ENTER == e.keyCode) {
        callback(e);
      }
    };
  };
  
$("#expand").click(function() {
  treeview.expand(".k-item");
});

$("#collapse").click(function() {
  treeview.collapse(".k-item");
});
```

```css
html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

#wrapper {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden; /* will contain if #first is longer than #second */
}

#expand {
    float:left; /* add this */
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#collapse {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden; /* if you don't want #second to wrap below #first */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>
        <div id="treeview"></div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <button id="expand" class="button1" >Expand button</button>
            <button id="collapse" class="button2" >Collapse button</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your response, your answer will expands only 1 level down, If I have more than 1 level child, it will not expands, my case I have 9th level down childs. Can you please let me know how to do that

Comment: Nope, i edited the example to have more layers and it still works. Maybe you build your treeview false?

Comment: Can you show me your dataSource in the question and how you init the treeView? I think the mistake lies there. But i can 100% assure you, that my answer is working like it should and like you asked :)